# Paypal DoDirectPayment Method Implementation in medium trusted hosting environment?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 application and using Paypal SDK for Paypal Website Pro.

I have created the API credentials like below.

```
using System;
using com.paypal.sdk.services;

using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
/**

 */
namespace GenerateCodeNVP
{
public class DoDirectPayment
{
    public DoDirectPayment()
    {
    }
    public string DoDirectPaymentCode(string paymentAction,string amount,string     
creditCardType,string creditCardNumber,string expdate_month,string cvv2Number,string 
firstName,string lastName,string address1,string city,string state,string zip,string 
countryCode,string currencyCode)
    {
        NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
        IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
        /*
         WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
         Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
         Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
         encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
         that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
         */

        // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, API operation and version.
        profile.APIUsername = "sdk-three_api1.sdk.com";
        profile.APIPassword = "QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q";
        profile.APISignature = 
"AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ";
        profile.Environment="sandbox";
        caller.APIProfile = profile;

        NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
        encoder["VERSION"] =  "51.0";   
        encoder["METHOD"] =  "DoDirectPayment";

        // Add request-specific fields to the request.
        encoder["PAYMENTACTION"] =  paymentAction;
        encoder["AMT"] =  amount;
        encoder["CREDITCARDTYPE"] =  creditCardType;        
        encoder["ACCT"] =  creditCardNumber;                        
        encoder["EXPDATE"] =  expdate_month;
        encoder["CVV2"] =  cvv2Number;
        encoder["FIRSTNAME"] =  firstName;
        encoder["LASTNAME"] =  lastName;                                        
        encoder["STREET"] =  address1;
        encoder["CITY"] =  city;    
        encoder["STATE"] =  state;          
        encoder["ZIP"] =  zip;  
        encoder["COUNTRYCODE"] = countryCode;
        encoder["CURRENCYCODE"] =  currencyCode;    

        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        string pStrrequestforNvp= encoder.Encode();
        string pStresponsenvp=caller.Call(pStrrequestforNvp);

        NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
        decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
        return decoder["ACK"];

    }
}

}
```

But some how I am not being to able to get success as the paypal sdk is giving me a medium trust issue.

The error description is:

```
That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers
```

Do any body have any idea how am I supposed to work around this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is that a message that the library is generating and returning or is that an actual message that the PayPal API is returning?

Comment: The first one. The exception is getting generated when the paypal api call is being made. Therefore, the request is not getting posted to paypal at all.